# Define a custom environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

I would like to have a script environment where I could write scripts for every slide.

I don't know if Beamer has such an environment, so I try to create my own as follows.

I would like this script environment to:

- have a larger width than that of Beamer's slides
- have some top and bottom margins

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{script}{
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{1.1\textwidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \scriptsize
}{
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{script}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{script}

\end{document}
```

However, the current problem is that there is a small space before the first letter of the first block. I hope either we remove completely this space (by preference) or have an indentation as the second block.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Put `\ignorespaces` at the end of the head of the environment definition as well, i.e., right after `\scriptsize`. You could also comment out the linebreak whitespace after `\begin{script}`, e.g., `\begin{script}%`, but the first way is probably more elegant.

Comment: @frabjous Your comment sounds like the solution to the problem. It would be nice of you could post it as an answer!